# accessing static final property in grails service

Tags: grails, groovy

I get a no such property error when trying to access the final properties of one class from inside a service class.

In a service I have the following code.

```
class ShiftService{
...
     def getEvents(shift){
        //if I try to access static final get error
        def type=shiftEvent.START;
        //NO SUCH PROPERTY shiftEvent for ShiftService


     }
...
}
//currently in same ShiftService.groovy file
class shiftEvent{

  static final String START="shiftStart";
  static final String END="shiftEnd";
  static final String DAY_BOUNDARY="dayBoundary";
  static final String CHECKIN="individualCheckin";
  static final String CHECKOUT="individualCheckout";
  static final String NIGHT_START="individualNightStart";
  static final String NIGHT_END="individualNightEnd";

...
```

}

Comment: `class shiftEvent` should be `class ShiftEvent`. That's one problem.

Comment: I think that's THE problem

Comment: ..yep. the problem. :(